# IOS Detect when a view will begin responding to touches

Tags: objective-c, ios, touches

I remember stumbling upon a method that would tell you when a view was ready to respond to touch events (and when it was not)..

Think, as an example, when the app comes into the foreground, the main view is not ready to respond (so if a user touches it, it would react).. as an aside, I know there are event handlers for determining when it is ready.. I'm just using this as an example.. the method I remember was something like

[UIView willBeginRespondingToTouches]

Anyone know the name of the actual method ?

Comment: I've never heard of anything like this. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: how about `becomesFirstResponder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found it..

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents]

So it wasnt a method for views, but for the app itself.
I'm using this to build a dynamic loading animation class (to intercept when ui is *uncontrollably* blocked)